# PSEXEC BATCH FILE

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a batch file using the following code:

```
@echo off

:: BatchGotAdmin
:-------------------------------------
REM  --> Check for permissions
>nul 2>&1 "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\cacls.exe" "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\config\system"

REM --> If error flag set, we do not have admin.
if '%errorlevel%' NEQ '0' (
    echo Requesting administrative privileges...
    goto UACPrompt
) else ( goto gotAdmin )

:UACPrompt
    echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    echo UAC.ShellExecute "%~s0", "", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"

    "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    exit /B

:gotAdmin
    if exist "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" ( del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" )
    pushd "%CD%"
    CD /D "%~dp0"
    goto KILLME
:--------------------------------------

:KILLME
CD "C:\Users\Justin\Desktop\PSTOOLS\"
psexec -s -i "cmd.exe"
```

Now, as you know if you have used PSEXEC in a batch file like this, Is starts one command prompt to launch PSEXEC, then it launches cmd.exe as the system account. How can I close the initial command prompt (not the one running as the system account) to make this batch file execute a bit cleaner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `-d` option to psexec to tell it not to wait for the new process to exit.